# ByteBuffer: readIString throwing illegal offset error

Tags: javascript, node.js, bytebuffer

I have a javascript application running. The problem is that when I try to read data from ByteBuffer, it throws the following error:

```
2020-07-17T09:11:21.503Z error [shim:_]                                           Unhandled Rejection reason RangeError: Illegal offset: 0 <= 4 (+168295178) <= 1276 promise Promise {
  <rejected> RangeError: Illegal offset: 0 <= 4 (+168295178) <= 1276
    at ByteBuffer.module.exports.ByteBufferPrototype.readUTF8String (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js:2117:27)
    at ByteBuffer.module.exports.ByteBufferPrototype.readIString (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js:1955:24)
    at Chaincode.Invoke (/usr/local/src/app.js:46:54)
    at handleMessage (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:636:47)
    at ChaincodeSupportClient.handleTransaction (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:361:9)
    at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:301:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11) }
```

The function which is being used to convert the ByteBuffer to string is below:

```
transient.get('data').flip().readIString()
```

The following json string is stored in the ByteBuffer:

```
{
        "transactionId": "xxxxxx",
        "collection": "xxxx",
        "requirementType": "xxxx",
        "requirementDisplayName": "xxxx",
        "locked": false 
};
```

I am using the following library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytebuffer

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**readIString(offset)** first reads a uint32 from the specified(or current) offset and use it as string length.

```
// https://github.com/protobufjs/bytebuffer.js/blob/5.0.1/dist/bytebuffer-node.js
var len = this.readUint32(offset);
var str = this.readUTF8String(len, ByteBuffer.METRICS_BYTES, offset += 4);
```

Your ByteBuffer seems not have correct length information at offset 0.

If you know string length, you can call **readUTF8String(len, ByteBuffer.METRICS_BYTES)** directly.

---

It seems that **writeUTF8String(str, offset)** does not write length information...

```
// https://github.com/protobufjs/bytebuffer.js/blob/5.0.1/dist/bytebuffer-node.js
k = Buffer.byteLength(str, "utf8");
offset += this.buffer.write(str, offset, k, "utf8");
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_write_string_offset_length_encoding